# Create tab dynamically after some div in first tabs

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

Create tab dynamically after showing 20 div in first tab.Actually I am generating a div dynamically,there may be 100 div generated dynamically.I want to show 20 div in one tab and if there are 100 div there it will automatically generate 5 tabs with 20 div in each tabs.

```
<div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels">
  <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">tab1</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">tab2</li>

  </ul>
  <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">

    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
        <div id="slider1" class="sliderwrapper">  
 <div class="contentdiv"> 
12345   
</div>
<div class="contentdiv"> 
12345   
</div>
</div>
<div id="paginate-slider1" class="pagination">   

</div>
<div id="paginate1-slider1" class="pagination2">

</div>   
    </div>

     </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: show what you have tried so far

Comment: Actually here i am not showing div generated dynamically, there are only 2 div in first tab. If there are 100 div (for eg <div class="contentdiv"> 12345 </div>) then I want to show 20 div in each tab and there must be 5 tabs generated...

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to achieve! Do you want empty divs to be generated? or there are already 100 divs which you want to move to different `tabs`?

Answer (score 1):

Here I created a jsFiddle which generates the tabs dynamically based on the number of contentDivs: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6HN9/ , it may help you achieve your goal.

the HTML code:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul id="tabLinks"></ul>
</div>
```

the JavaScript code:

```
$(function () {

    var neededDivCount = 100; // number of contentDivs for test purposes
    var divPerTab = 20; // number of contentDivs / tabs for test purposes

    // create the conentDivs dynamically for test purposes

    for (var i = 1; i <= neededDivCount; i++) {
        $("body").append('<div class="contentDiv">div' + i + 'content</div>');
    }

    // create the tabs and tabLinks based on the number of contentDivs in the document

    var neededTabCount = Math.floor(($(".contentDiv").length - 1) / divPerTab) + 1;
    for (var i = 1; i <= neededTabCount; i++) {
        $("#tabs").append('<div id="tab' + i + '"></div>');
        $("#tabLinks").append('<li><a href="#tab' + i + '">tab' + i + '</a></li>');
    }

    // loop through the contentDivs and append them to the correct tab

    $(".contentDiv").each(function (index) {
        var appendToTabIndex = Math.floor(index / divPerTab) + 1;
        $(this).appendTo($("#tab" + appendToTabIndex));
    });

    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

Comment: actually I dont have 100 divs its is generated dynamically.......this is an example I am trying to explain.........there may be 60 divs then there must be 3 tabs with 20 div in each tab...also how can I show the data in contentdiv dynamically using c#.

Comment: @AmitSambyal : since the code uses jQuery class selector, it can do the trick for any number of divs it finds with a class name "contentDiv". I created 100 contentDivs only for demonstration purposes, but because the class selector, the code after the creation of these contentDivs can be used to any number of contentDivs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 nested repeaters.. The child one is generated from datatable the returns your content records (content divs) and the parent one is dynamically generated from Anonymous types list.

**ASPX**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="RP.aspx.cs" Inherits="RP" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
      });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="tabs">

        <%-- Tabs Links --%>
        <asp:Repeater ID="TablLinkRepeater" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <ul>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li><a href="#Tab<%# Eval("TabIndex") %>">Tab
                    <%# Eval("TabIndex") %></a></li>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </ul>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <%-- Tabs and Content --%>
        <asp:Repeater ID="TabRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="Tab<%# Eval("TabIndex") %>">
                    <%-- Show TabIndex just for testing --%>
                    <h1>
                        Tab #
                        <%# Eval("TabIndex") %>
                    </h1>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="ContentRepeater" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="Content" id="ContentDiv" runat="server">
                                <%-- Some content--%>
                                <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class RP : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private const int ContentPerTab = 20;

    private DataTable SomeDatatable;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {   

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //1) Load SomeDatatable from Database somehow
            // Just for testing : replace with query to DB
            SomeDatatable = new DataTable("x");
            SomeDatatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ContentIndex", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
            SomeDatatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", Type.GetType("System.String")));
            for (int x = 1; x <= 50; x++)
            {
                SomeDatatable.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                x,
                "Content " + x
            });
            }
            ///////////////////

            //2) Create a dummy data source for the tab repeater using a list of anonymous types
            List<object> TabList = new List<object>();


            for (int I = 0; I < Math.Ceiling((decimal)SomeDatatable.Rows.Count / (decimal)ContentPerTab); I++)
            {
                TabList.Add(new { TabIndex = I });
            }

            TabRepeater.ItemDataBound += TabRepeater_ItemDataBound;
            TabRepeater.DataSource = TabList;
            TabRepeater.DataBind();

            TablLinkRepeater.DataSource = TabList;
            TablLinkRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }



    protected void TabRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item | e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            int TabIndex = -1;
            int.TryParse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "TabIndex").ToString(), out TabIndex);

            //Copy Content Rows from SomeDatable that belong to this tab
            DataTable Dt = SomeDatatable.Clone();
            for (Int32 i = TabIndex * ContentPerTab; i <= (TabIndex + 1) * ContentPerTab - 1; i++)
            {
                if (i >= SomeDatatable.Rows.Count) break;

                Dt.ImportRow(SomeDatatable.Rows[i]);
            }

            // Find the content repeater in this item and use the new datatable as source
            Repeater ContentRepeater = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("ContentRepeater");

            ContentRepeater.ItemDataBound += ContentRepeater_ItemDataBound;

            ContentRepeater.DataSource = Dt;
            ContentRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }

    //This handler might be needed for content repeater, included just for testing 
    protected void ContentRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item | e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            //Read coulmn from Datarow
            int ContentIndex = -1;
            int.TryParse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ContentIndex").ToString(), out ContentIndex);

            // Find some label
            Label Name = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Name");
            Name.Text = "Content #" + ContentIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i add data-info property to the radio button generated dynamically

Comment: I am able to create an application using 2 nested repeaters but I am not able to show the first question on load....it is showing first question when I click next or previous button

Comment: If my answer works for your question, please mark it as answer. And for further questions please post a new question with sample code so other people would see your question and help you.\